# $route.reload() is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing, angularjs-ng-route

I am using AngularJs to build application. In IE, data is not getting refreshed, even after calling `$route.reload()`. But it is working fine in other browsers. Even I have test it different system, still I'm facing same issue.

Here is the code

```
Service.methodname(data1)
    .success(function (data, status, header, config) {
        $scope.response = data;
        $('#mySchedulElection').modal('hide');                  
        if (data == 1) {
            $scope.showmessage('Election successfully saved', $scope.MessageType.success);
            $route.reload();            
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try ,  $location.refresh();

Comment: Object doesn't support property or method 'refresh' - getting this error. i have injected the $location service

Comment: @ArunKumarM You have to declare in the controller/module/factrory/directive" The $location variable and then use it as $location.refresh();

Answer (score 0):

Check your cache policy in Service. By default AngularJs will cache your requests.
Try using

```
$http.get('url', {cache: false});
```

Maybe it is a better idea to create a Cache object for this request to better control of the cache behavior.

```
$http.get('url', {cache: serviceCache});
```

and then you can invalidate the cache when you need it:

```
serviceCache.removeAll();
```

See

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache))

for more info